# Python: printing strings and data frames

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to create a report using python to populate the data. Below is an example. I have used `pandas` to read the `csv` to create the data frame. I then have to use the cells to populate the text.

Dataframe:

```
    name    age
0   Chris   15
1   Kim     20
2   David   18
```

How do I get python to print the following:

```
name is Chris age 15.
name is Kim age 20.
name is David age 18.
```

Answer (score 2):

Code:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({'name': ['Chris', 'Kim', 'David'],
                         'age': [15, 20, 18]})

for index, row in data.iterrows():
  print('name is {} age {}.'.format(row['name'], row['age']))
```

Output:

```
name is Chris age 15.
name is Kim age 20.
name is David age 18.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [12]: import pandas as pd

In [13]: df = pd.DataFrame([
    ...:     {'name': 'Chris', 'age': 15},
    ...:     {'name': 'Kim', 'age': 20},
    ...:     {'name': 'David', 'age': 18}
    ...: ])

In [14]: df
Out[14]: 
   age   name
0   15  Chris
1   20    Kim
2   18  David

In [15]: for name, age in zip(df['name'], df['age']):
    ...:     # Python 3.6+ 
    ...:     print(f'name is {name} age {age}')
    ...:
    ...:     # Python 3.5 and below
    ...:     # print('name is {name} age {age}'.format(**df.to_dict()))
    ...:     
name is Chris age 15
name is Kim age 20
name is David age 18

In [16]:
```

Answer (score 1):

Use lambda to iterate over

```
import pandas
data = pandas.DataFrame({'name': ['Chris', 'Kim', 'David'],
                         'age': [15, 20, 18]})
def print_func(x):
    print('name is {} and age is {}'.format(x['name'],x['age']))

data.apply(lambda x:print_func(x),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
name is Chris and age is 15
name is Kim and age is 20
name is David and age is 18
```